# In the Chrome Developer Tools console frame list, how to show extension name instead of ID?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

For debugging purposes, in the Chrome developer tools console tab, in the frame list it used to show extensions by their name not by their ID. It seems like in the recent version of Chrome it shows the ID now instead of the name. Is there any way to change it back to show the extension name instead?

Comment: It's not customizable. Report the bug on http://crbug.com, and we'll star it.

Comment: This frankly sounds like a bug more than anything. Yes, please report this and share the issue report here.

Comment: I added the issue report here
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=643766#